# Wavefunction at origin and derivative of potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation

I am working on a problem to prove that for a bound-state particle with orbital angular momentum $\ell=0$ in a central potential,

> $$ |\psi(0)|^2 \text{ is proportional to } \left\langle
>  \frac{dV}{dr}\right\rangle$$

I started off by writing the radial equation for $u(r)$

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2u(r)}{dr^2} + V(r)u(r) = Eu(r)$$

Multiplying by $u'(r)$ and integrating from 0 to infinity:

$$\int_0^{\infty}-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2u(r)}{dr^2} u'(r) + V(r)u(r)u'(r)\ dr = \int_0^{\infty} Eu(r) u'(r)\ dr$$

Using integration by parts:

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} (u'(r))^2\rvert_0^\infty +  \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} u''(r)u'(r) \ dr  + V(r)u(r)^2\rvert_0^\infty - \int_0^{\infty} (V'(r)u(r)^2 + V(r)u(r)u'(r))\ dr = Eu(r)^2\rvert_0^\infty - \int_0^{\infty} Eu(r)u'(r) \ dr$$

Among the 7 terms, the 2nd, 5th and 7th terms cancel.

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} (u'(r))^2\rvert_0^\infty  + V(r)u(r)^2\rvert_0^\infty - \int_0^{\infty} V'(r)u(r)^2 \ dr = Eu(r)^2\rvert_0^\infty $$

I recognise that the 3rd term above is $\left\langle
 \frac{dV}{dr}\right\rangle$. But I am unable to simplify the remaining terms - I can evaluate the limits at $r=\infty$ to be 0 but I am unable to handle the limits at $r=0$. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking for a week, I solved the problem. As explained, the limits at $r=\infty$ vanish. Now, the key is to notice that $u(r)\sim r$ as $r\to 0$. This causes the limit $E(u(0))^2$ to vanish; also if we make the usual assumption that the potential $V(r)$ is not too singular so that $\lim\limits_{r\to 0}r^2 V(r) = 0$, then similarly $V(0)(u(0))^2$ vanish.

The coup de grace is then to note that

$$R(0) = \lim\limits_{r\to 0}\frac{u(r)}{r} = \lim\limits_{r\to 0} \frac{u'(r)}{1}$$

where we applied L'hopital's rule. Putting everything together,

$$\frac{\hbar}{2m}(R(0))^2 = \left\langle \frac{dV}{dr}\right\rangle$$

Finally, since $\psi(0) = R(0)/\sqrt{4\pi}$, we conclude that

$$|\psi(0)|^2 = \frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{2m}{\hbar}\left\langle \frac{dV}{dr}\right\rangle$$

**Remark:** We can check that this is true for the $l=0$ states of hydrogen, for which $|\psi(0)|^2 = \frac{1}{\pi n^3a_0^3}$